# Type Cast from strong id to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, casting

I used core data for saving my data and have one property named "timestamp" which is defined as "NSDate". I use my helper class to get data object from core data by following code:

```
- (id)getMaxValue:(NSString *)entityName forProperty:(NSString *)propertyName {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName];

    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:propertyName ascending:NO]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    id maxValue = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error].firstObject;

    if ([maxValue count]) {
        [self.context rollback];

        return [maxValue valueForKey:propertyName];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }

}
```

In my controller I used the following code to check if there is any returned result, I get the timestamp of it:

```
id maxGroupsDate = [self.generalModel getMaxValue:@"MyEntityName" forProperty:@"timestamp"];
if (maxGroupsDate != nil) {
    maxGroupsDate = (NSDate*) maxGroupsDate;
    NSTimeInterval maxGroupsTimestamp = maxGroupsDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
}
```

However it cause such an error:

```
Property 'timeIntervalSince1970' not found on object of type '__strong id'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This statement has no effect:

```
maxGroupsDate = (NSDate*) maxGroupsDate;
```

Instead, introduce a new variable of the specified type and also check the value is `NSDate` before casting:

```
if ([maxGroupsDate isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
    NSDate *date = (NSDate *)maxGroupsDate;
    NSTimeInterval maxGroupsTimestamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970;
}
```

That last statement won't have much effect either, but I'm guess you added that for illustration only.